# Eclipse Mars starts with exit code=1 when using JDK 8

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, eclipse-mars

I plan moving to Eclipse Mars and recently installed the 64 Bit version on Windows 7. Since the JBoss Tools require Java 8, I also downloaded JDK 8u51 and unzipped it to my `Programs (x86)` folder. I want to keep JDK 1.7.0 as my system's default JVM, so I did not fully *install* Java 8.

Furthermore, I updated my `eclipse.ini`, so it points to the new JVM. With JDK 1.7.0 my Eclipse Mars installation launched without any problems, with JDK 8 it does not start and returns with `exit code=1`, however.

Am I missing anything out? The error message is not much of a help, sadly.

This is my launch configuration:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk8_51/bin/javaw.exe
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Xmn128m
-Xss2m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
```

**Edit:** Eclipse error log:

http://postimg.org/image/7iugfivub/

Comment: what's the content of the error log? Have you tried launching it with `-clean`?

Comment: try setting it as `C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk8_51/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll`

Comment: Neither ``-clean`` nor pointing to the ``jvm.dll`` file helped. Eclipse error log is attached to initial question.

Comment: Are you sure both eclipse and java is 32 bit? *For the 32-bit Eclipse executable (eclipse.exe on Windows) a 32-bit JVM must be used and for the 64-bit Eclipse executable a 64-bit JVM must be used. 32-bit Eclipse will not work with a 64-bit JVM.*

Comment: Yes, I chose both Eclipse Mars and JDK to be 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed out unpacking the `*.pack` files:

```
for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar"
```

Since I did not *install* the JDK, but simply *unzipped* it for sake of simplicity, I forgot about the packaged JARs. Now my JDK is up and running, plus Eclipse Mars starts without an error.

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your JDK should be 64 bit. Download the Windows x64 version:   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

and point your '-vm' to it.

Comment: The JDK I downloaded is 64 bit already: ``jdk-8u51-windows-x64.exe``